# How to prove $ \sum_{0}^{\infty} (\sin(x))^n $ converges or diverges for different values of x?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have attempted to use the idea of geometric series and got that it converges for x< arcsin(1) and x> -arcsin(1). But since this is a series showing this doesn't seem sufficient ?

Comment: Hmmm, what are $\arcsin(\pm1)$ already? And when is $|\sin x|<1$?

Comment: Why isn't it sufficient ? if $x\neq \pi/2\pmod{\pi}$ then $|sin(x)|<1$ so this is the term of a convergent geometric series as you mentioned. And elsewhere the series is $\sum 1$ or $\sum(-1)^n$ both divergent.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the $\sin(x)$ is just disguising a simple question.  All that matters is the value of $\sin(x)$, let's call that $y$.  We know that $-1 \leq  y \leq 1$.  So, we are looking at:
$$ \sum_{0}^{\infty} y^n $$ which is known to converge provided that $|y| < 1$.  We have 3 cases: $y = 1$ which clearly does not converge, $y = -1$ which also does not converge but for a slightly different reason, and $-1 < y < 1$ which will converge.

Comment: Would you be able to expand on the 'slightly different reason' ?

Comment: When $y = 1$, all the terms are $1$ and the partial sums are $1, 2, 3, . . .$. They grow without limit. .  When $y = -1$, the terms alternate between $1$ and $-1$ so the partial sums alternate between $1$ and $0$.  They do not grow without limit but they do not converge either.

Comment: Is using the term "sum of a geometric progression" not the simplest answer... with its classical condition of convergence ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I guessed that the OP was thrown by the $sin(x)$ which I guessed was intended to cause confusion.  So, I concentrated on that aspect.